# How to achieve the following Map functionality using leaflet.js (screenshot attached)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

I want achieve the following map functionality in my maps.
When i am zoomed out the properties appear something like this ->

[[image: Zoomed out map [1]]

But when i zoom in map changes to following ->

[image: zoomed in map]

I want to achieve this using leaflet.js but i dont have ant idea how to achieve this?
I have lat-long data for the properties and i want to achieve this for properties all over the world.

so when map is maxed zoomed out it look something like this ->

[image]

you can visit actual website for Demo :- https://elocations.com/retail-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is called "clustering". A quick search will give you some "off the shelf" libraries.

Ex: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster